# Can't append new variables to my python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am making a language in python called PythonScript, which is a JavaScript and Python (not Python 3) mix.

I am adding variables, but when I do the following code I don't get the expected result.

```
var scuffles = hi!
```

I have tried to debug it, and as you will see in my code I made a debugging array, which I found to be empty. I looked up some tutorials, but none were covering what I am trying to do.

This is a portion of the file:

```py
    import os
    import sys

    programDebugingArray1 = []
    functions = ["Console"]
    functionCodes = [["out \"TEST\""]]
    programVariables = {}

    def lex(cm,stri,nums,toWake):
        i = 0
        if cm == "":
            console()
    elif cm == "var" or cm == "=":
            pass
        elif cm == "--vars":
            print(programVariables)
        elif cm == "--debugManual1":
            print(programDebugingArray1)
        else:
            print("\""+cm+"\" was not recognized as a PythonScript command.")
        console()
    def console():
        commandToRun = ""
        tok = ""
        string = ""
        varValue = ""
        newVarName = ""
        Strings = []
        Numbers = []
        functionToCall = ""
        state = 0
        command = input()
        for char in command:
            tok += char
            if state == 1:
                string += char
            elif state == 2:
                if char == " ":
                    char = ""
                newVarName += char
            elif state == 3:
                varValue += char
            if (tok == "\"" or tok == "'") or (char == "\"" or char == "'"):
                if state == 0:
                    state = 1
                elif state == 1:
                    state = 0
                    string = string[0:len(string) - 1]
                    Strings.append(string)
                    string = ""
                tok = ""
                char = ""
            elif tok == " ":
                tok = ""
            elif tok == "var" and state == 0:
                state = 2
                tok = ""
            elif tok == "=" and state == 2:
                state = 3
                tok = ""
            elif tok == "!" and state == 3:
                programDebugingArray1.append(newVarName)
                programDebugingArray1.append(varValue)
                state == 0
                programVariables[newVarName] = varValue
                tok = ""
            elif tok == "--vars" and state == 0:
                commandToRun == "--vars"
                tok = ""
            elif tok == "--debugManual1" and state == 0:
                commandToRun == "--debugManual1"
                tok = ""
        if commandToRun == "":
            commandToRun = command
        lex(commandToRun,Strings,Numbers,functionToCall)
    console()
```

I expected the debug array to at least have something in it, but for some reason it and the variables dictionary is empty. There are no error messages or boots out of the console.

Comment: Based on your all-caps disclaimer, it sounds like you already tried to narrow this down a bit, which is good. But that's still 76 lines of what at a glance looks like a bunch of command line argument parsing? If you need help with variable declarations, please narrow your code down to the parts pertaining to *variable declaration*. Those of us who are helping you for free don't want to sift through half of your program to find the problem.

Comment: My guess is that you're not reaching the part of the code that appends to the debug arrays.  Try putting print statements on the path you think the code should take for your input, and see where it's actually going.